# What is the meaning of "dimension key"?

Tags: database-design, dimensional-modeling

I am a beginner trying to understand the basic concepts of database's. I know several types of keys (Primary key, Foreign key, candidate key, super key, surrogate key.....etc). While learning about the degenerate dimension, I came across "dimension key".

> In a data warehouse, a degenerate dimension is a dimension key in the fact table that does not have its own dimension table        ----Ralph Kimball

Could someone please helps me understand the **dimension key** ?

Comment: If you are a beginner you should probably leave data warehouse design concepts for now and focus more on normalization forms.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A **dimension key** is the primary key of a [dimension table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_schema).

In the example below, the "Time_key" column is the dimension/primary key of the Time dimension. This column will be used to join the dimension with fact tables, just like any other key.

[image: Time dimension example]

in https://www.kimballgroup.com/1997/07/its-time-for-time/

A [degenerate dimension](https://www.kimballgroup.com/data-warehouse-business-intelligence-resources/kimball-techniques/dimensional-modeling-techniques/degenerate-dimension/) is, however, a different and slightly more advanced concept to model. In the degenerate dim case, a fact table contains a foreign key that, by design, does not link to a dimension.